# Office 365 Excel can't be embed in place inside Windows native application

Tags: c++, excel, office365

I embed a Office Excel in a Win32 application using MFC `COleDocObjectItem`. I use `DoVerb(OLEIVERB_SHOW,...)` to show the Excel. By the version 2002(12527.22060) of Office 365, the Excel can be embed in place normally inside the application. But in the newer version of Office 365, the Excel always popup out of the application. I try `DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE,...)` to force Excel show in place, but it doesn't work.

Does Office 365 Excel not support embed in place no longer? Is there any method to make Excel embed in place in new version of Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the Display settings from "Optimize for best appearance" to "Optimize for compatibility"?

[Display Settings in Office](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVfY.png)