# Office 365 Word can't be embed in place inside Windows native application

Tags: .net, mfc, office365, ole-automation

I embed Office Word in a .NET application using MFC COleDocObjectItem. I use DoVerb(OLEIVERB_SHOW,...) to show Word.
Until very recently it was working well, Word could be embed in place normally inside the application.
But with newer version (2204 16.0.15128.20178) of Office 365, Microsoft Word always popup out of the application on some Windows 10 machines but not all.

We noticed on two machines where the issue happened the same dump showing an issue in MFC140u:
Faulting application name: XXXXXXXXXXX.exe, version: X.X.X.X, time stamp: 0x6194d628
Faulting module name: mfc140u.dll, version: 14.10.25017.0, time stamp: 0x58a64535
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000028318d
Faulting process id: 0x4304
Faulting application start time: 0x01d87515fd8b29c9
Faulting application path: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\mfc140u.dll
Report Id: afb20b8f-5f55-4b23-992d-8c5088a8d955
Faulting package full name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

That looks very similar to what is described here with another Microsoft Office application: [Office 365 Excel can't be embed in place inside Windows native application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149278/office-365-excel-cant-be-embed-in-place-inside-windows-native-application/72476668#72476668)

We tried to uninstall Office and reinstall it but it didn't fix the problem.

We tried to remove Office completely using Microsoft tool and reinstall it, but it didn't solve the issue either.

We are guessing some environmental issues or registry issues but so far we have not ben able to reproduce on other machines and we have not been able to figure out what the issue could be.

We just diagnosed that it is happening with Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20002.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The issue could be anywhere, including your code. The fact that it surfaces in an MFC module is no indication that the issue is internal to MFC. The fact that the issue started appearing now is also no indication that the actual bug was introduced recently. It could have been around forever, and just never materialized. The diagnostics report shows an access violation exception, an attempt to read/write/or execute invalid memory, frequently the result of getting object lifetimes wrong.

Comment: Try [collecting user-mode dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) on affected machines to further analyze the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable but we found a clear reproduction. The same code worked for years and was working until Office 365 version 2108. It started to break with the last Current Channel Update and very recently with the Semi Annual update (2205 and 2206).

Comment: A case has been opened at Microsoft. We find out that OLE in-place activation is no longer working with Office version 2205 and 2206. The problem can be reproduced in Word and trying to insert an Excel object. Excel will open outside of Word and not inside as it should be.

Comment: @HuguesJ. We just ran into the exact same issue. Any news on how to fix this or a workaround you've developed?

Answer (score 1):

@Soko,

The issue is DPI related. There has been a change in MS-Word enforcing additional DPI related requirements for OLE in-place activation.
The most recent versions Office will check if the DPI values of the embedded Office app and the container app are equal, if a difference is found Office does not open embedded.

Therefore, you need to set the DPI awareness of your application 'i.e. container) through the manifest of the application. Setting the DPI awareness in the config file is not enough.
Check these articles from Microsoft, they should point you to the changes required:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution#ole
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

We applied the changes required and it work now with the latest version of MS-Word (2206 and above).

Hope this will help.

Hugues